# CryptoJS.AES.encrypt PHP equivalent

Tags: php, encryption, cryptojs

I am trying to create a PHP function equivalent to this JS lines with CryptoJS:

```
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("string", CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('aCIbjMuVGtwF8nlSKoPydE=='), {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
        iv: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('JAwlt7SNbYLycmPRqeDFou==')
    }).toString();
```

I was trying to do this in PHP but it doesn't give me the same results:

```
<?php 

const METHOD = 'aes-256-ctr';

$keyAndIV = array(
             "key" => "68221b8ccb951adc05f279522a83f274",
             "iv"  => hex2bin("240c25b7b48d6d82f27263d1a9e0c5a2")
           );
           

$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(
                               $plaintext,
                               self::METHOD,
                               $keyAndIV["key"],
                               OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
                               $keyAndIV["iv"]
                            );

$ciphertext = bin2hex($ciphertext);
$ciphertext = base64_encode($ciphertext);

echo $ciphertext;
?>
```

How can I know exactly the key, iv and the method I have to use in PHP based on JS code?

Regards

Comment: In the PHP code, try aes-128-cbc, hex decode the key (analogous to the iv) and omit the hex encoding of the ciphertext.

Comment: Hi @Topaco, thanks, I tried the configuration you indicated, but I'm getting different results for string "test". JS: "v6cM3X072luIAH3EKLsF + A ==", PHP without base64_encode: "bfa70cdd7d3bda5b88007dc428bb05f8", PHP with base64_encode: "YmZhNzBjZGQ3ZDNiZGE1Yjg4MDA3Z" I used hex2bin for $ key and $ iv

Comment: I got the string "68221b8ccb951adc05f279522a83f274" by this line:  CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('aCIbjMuVGtwF8nlSKoPydE==').toString(); Is that right? Then I apply hex2bin("68221b8ccb951adc05f279522a83f274") for the key. Same thing to the iv

Comment: Skip the hex encoding of the ciphertext. i.e. remove the line `$ciphertext = bin2hex($ciphertext);`

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks @Topaco, I'll post the final code.

Answer (score 0):

here's the final working PHP code:

```
<?php
$plaintext  = "test";
$method     = 'aes-128-cbc';

$key = hex2bin("68221b8ccb951adc05f279522a83f274");
$iv  = hex2bin("240c25b7b48d6d82f27263d1a9e0c5a2");
           
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(
                               $plaintext,
                               $method,
                               $key,
                               OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
                               $iv
                            );

$ciphertext = base64_encode($ciphertext);

echo $ciphertext;
?>
```

Special thanks to Topaco.

Regards.