# CryptoJS AES encrypt (with key size 128 / 8) equivalent in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, cryptojs

I am newbie in PHP and I was trying to achieve the CryptoJS AES encryption equivalent in PHP. I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62660335/cryptojs-aes-encrypt-php-equivalent) but unfortunately I was not able to achieve the same. I was getting a different output in PHP code as encrypted string.

Where did I go wrong?

**Javascript Code**

```
const customerObject = {
  CustomerName: "test",
  EmailID: "tester@test.com",
  Street: "Test",
  City: "London",
  Country: "United Kingdom",
  ZipCode: "XXX XXX",
};

const token = "8056483646328123";

const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(token);
const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(token);

const returnEncrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
  CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(customerObject),
  key,
  {
    iv: iv,
    keySize: 128 / 8,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
  }
);
```

**PHP Code**

```
 <?php
    
    $customer = [
       'CustomerName' => "test",
       'EmailID' => "tester@test.com",
       'Street' => "Test",
       'City' => "London",
       'Country' => "United Kingdom",
       'ZipCode' => "XXX XXX",
    ];
    
    
    $plaintext  = json_encode($customer);
    $method     = 'AES-128-CBC';
    
    $key = hex2bin("8056483646328123");
    $iv  = hex2bin("8056483646328123");
    
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(
       $plaintext,
       $method,
       $key,
       OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
       $iv
    );
    
    
    $ciphertext = base64_encode($ciphertext);

    echo $ciphertext;
    
    ?>
```

Comment: I tried your PHP code and got the following warning - ```openssl_encrypt(): IV passed is only 8 bytes long, cipher expects an IV of precisely 16 bytes, padding with \0```. Could it be that CryptoJS implements padding somewhat differently? I also found a bug report that might be relevant - https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/293

Comment: Thanks for responding quickly. The crypto js one works perfectly in our app. But in PHP code, I don't know if the method - 'AES-128-CBC' is causing the error.

Comment: Probably you mean `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(customerObject))`. In the PHP code, the key and IV must not be hex decoded, i.e. remove both `hex2bin()`.  `'AES-128-CBC'` is OK. By the way, using the key as IV is insecure.

Comment: Thankyou @Topaco for the solution. It worked when I removed the ```hex2bin()``` from the code. I will add the solution under this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Topaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014097/topaco) pointed out in comments, the **key** and **IV** must not be hex decoded, i.e. remove both hex2bin().

The corrected code is given below.

```
<?php
    
    $customer = [
       'CustomerName' => "test",
       'EmailID' => "tester@test.com",
       'Street' => "Test",
       'City' => "London",
       'Country' => "United Kingdom",
       'ZipCode' => "XXX XXX",
    ];
    
    
    $plaintext  = json_encode($customer);
    $method     = 'AES-128-CBC';
    
    $key = "8056483646328123";
    $iv  = "8056483646328123";
    
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(
       $plaintext,
       $method,
       $key,
       OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
       $iv
    );
    
    
    $ciphertext = base64_encode($ciphertext);

    echo $ciphertext;
    
    ?>
```